# Custom static cells programmatically

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have many Custom Cells (xib file + swift subclass of UITableViewCell) and in many scenes, I use them as dynamic cells and everything works well (register cell, dequeue etc).

My problem occurs when I need to have a static tableView which can also use those cells. I can't and I don't want to use a storyboard to achieve this, because I'd lose reusability.

I tried something like below but it shows plain `UITableViewCell` instead of my designed in xib `CustomCell`. Looks like it doesn't load subviews of cells from the nib.

```
private lazy var cells: [UITableViewCell] = [
    CustomCell1(),
    CustomCell2(),
    CustomCell3(),
]

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cells.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return cells[indexPath.row]
}
```

How to create `UITableView` with static custom cells programmatically?

**EDIT**
The answer for @thedp. Custom Cells are designed like this. This is a just example:

```
final class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak private var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak private var textView: MyCustomTextView!
    @IBOutlet weak private var doneButton: MyCustomButton!
    func configureCell(with: ...) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `CustomCell` ?

Answer (score 2):

1) register cells as you are doing usual for dynamic UITableView.

2) set dataSource of UITableView

3) store cells identifier in private lazy var cells: [UITableViewCell] instead of allocated cells

4) then do next

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifer = cells[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
    cellIdentifer, for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Also you can dequeue cells in viewDidLoad() method and store them into array. But dequeueReusableCell is required, you can just allocate them from class